# Javascript won't overwrite CSS display property

Tags: javascript, css

I have a DIV that is set do display:none from CSS and it's supposed to be made visible (`style.display = '';`) at some point by javascript.

The problem is that if I put the `display:none` in the CSS file the javascript does not seem to have any effect. I have also tried changing the background color instead of the display property, and that works.

I have the code running [here](http://clienti.bsorin.ro/florin2/cautare) (just press the edit link).

I really thank you for taking the time to look into this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set it to `block` or `inline` using Javascript.

Writing `style.display = ""` will clear any `display` set in the inline style, and cause it to revert to whatever it inherited from CSS.

Alternatively, you can change the element's `className` using Javascript so that the CSS rule no longer applies.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `style.display = ''` only affects inline styles on an element. It doesn't change the style sheet.

You should set it to whatever `display` you need:

```
style.display = 'block';
```

or add a class that represents the style you want.

Answer (score 0):

other way to hide content is use `opacity=0` and to again make `visible` use `opacity=1` thats it....!!!